# Supabase onAuthStateChange() triggers when switching tabs in React

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, supabase

I have the following code in my React project using Supabase:

```
// supabaseClient.ts
export const onAuthStateChangedListener = (callback) => {
    supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange(callback);
};
```

```
// inside user context
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChangedListener((event, session) => {
        console.log(event);
    });

    return unsubscribe;
}, []);
```

However, every time I switch tabs away from the tab rendering the website to something else, and back, I see a new log from this listener, even if literally no change happened on the website.

Does anyone know the reason for this? The useEffect inside my user context component is the only place in my app where the listener is being called. To test, I wrote this dummy function inside my supabaseClient.ts file:

```
const testFunction = async () => {
    supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange(() => {
        console.log("auth state has changed");
    });
};

testFunction()
```

This function also renders every time I switch tabs. This makes it a little annoying because my  components that are related to userContext re render every time a tab is switched, so if a user is trying to update their profile data or something, they cannot switch tabs away in the middle of editing their data.

Answer (score 0):

Supabase onAuthStateChange by default triggers every time a tab is switched. To prevent this, when initializing the client, add `{multiTab: false}` as a parameter.

Example:

```
const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseAnonKey, {multiTab: false,});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to the same problem. The way I've found is saving the access token value in a cookie every time the session changes, and retrieve it when onAuthStateChange get triggered, so I can decide to not update anything if the session access token is the same.

```js
// >> Subscribe to auth state changes
  useEffect(() => {
    let subscription: Subscription
    async function run() {
      subscription = Supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange(async (event, newSession) => {
        // get current token from manually saved cookie every time session changes
        const currentAccessToken = await getCurrentAccessToken()

        if (currentAccessToken != newSession?.access_token) {
          console.log('<<<  SUPABASE SESSION CHANGED  >>>')
          authStateChanged(event, newSession)
        } else {
          console.log('<<<  SUPABASE SESSION NOT CHANGED  >>>')
        }
      }).data.subscription

      // ** Get the user's session on load
      await me()
    }
    run()

    return function cleanup() {
      // will be called when the component unmounts
      if (subscription) subscription.unsubscribe()
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [])
```